# Stripe border or contour detection in grayscale image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an grayscale image, and I've tried some methods such as findContour and HoughLinesP to detect the stripe in the image attached. The output does not reflect the expected detection. One of my example codes is below, using findContour. However, the script detects other regions outside the stripe area.

How could the stripe (contour/border) be detected properly?

```
import cv2
import imutils

img = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cnts = cv2.findContours(image=thresh, mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                   method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

img_col = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

image_copy = img_col.copy()
cv2.drawContours(image=image_copy, contours=[c], contourIdx=-1,
             color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
# see the results
cv2.imshow('Output', image_copy)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

Comment: how can it vary in appearance? is it always in the picture? is it always in the same place? is it always darkening the same amount? what do we see? what is that? how does it happen?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That stripe/pattern is always in the picture. The stripe is not necessarily in the same place (if you're referring to other similar images to process). The darkening is fairly the same. The image depicts two materials joined by another material (stripe).

Comment: Is stripe always horizontal or it can be under some angle (big enough to not be considered horizontal)?

Comment: @MilosStojanovic The stripe is always horizontal.

Comment: Is it always darker than anything else in the image? If so, threshold first to isolate the line as best you can. Then use morphology to clean it up. Then get your contour, etc.

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, the stripe material is always darker.

Comment: what is that circular pattern? how does it happen? how is the picture taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know dark stripe is horizontal, checking the mean value for each rows may be able to be help.

The figure below is just drawing each row with mean value. (sinse data is 1D, width of this figure is meaningless).

[image]

From this data, extracting a pair of y values(upper and lower y value of the dark band) is easy.
I obtained the value (200, 219). Drawing them as horizontal lines on source image becomes:

[image]

I guess, information like this can be used to refine your result.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please include some code lines to your answer for completeness?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not python user, so I used C++ to try little this, and intentionally avoided to show such C++ code in this post. Because I guess this post is enough without any code, and also it seems that including C++ code in answer for [python]+[opencv] tagged question is hated in this site.